# Remove entry from file based on user input.

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a config file with file locations in it, what I would like to do is gather user input and if that input is in the file..
Remove this from the file.
This is what I have so far...

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-r', action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.r:
        f = open('config.dat', 'r')
        remove_contents = f.read()
        #How to read input from user input and remove line from config.dat
        f.close()
```

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: what is your user input and what do you want to delete? Did you read about databases and json files so far?

Comment: user would run ./script.py -r file1.txt.  If this file is located in config then this would remove other wise "file is not here" and exit.  Thanks

Comment: are you trying to remove the entry or remove a file based on that entry?

Comment: Just remove the entry from that .dat file

Answer (score 0):

Text Files are not the best way of managing data like you are doing currently. You basically have to read everything in memory and then rewrite it. Here is one solution.

```
#Read Content
f = open("config.dat","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

#Write it back, but skip the line which should be deleted
f = open("config.dat","w")
for line in lines:
    print line
    if line!="ruhuru"+"\n": #Replace this string with your arg var
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Content of the config.dat file is as follows:

```
blabla
ruhuru
gugug
kukuku
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are opening file only for reading. if you want change anything in file open it with argue 'r+'. Like this:

```
f = open('config.dat', 'r+')
```

After that you have to split config file to lines.

```
remove_contents = remove_contents.split('\n')
```

For checking lines if they content input 'args', you can use for loope like this.

```
for line in remove_contents:
    if line != args:
        f.write(line + '\n')
```

First line: Read every line in remove_contents whose is split to lines. 
Second line: Check if line doesn't content 'args'.
Third line: Write line if it's condition OK.

Comment: If you don't use a context manager, and you are on a Windows system, you might lock the file if you not do `f.close()`

Comment: I added something like this:
script.py -r newtest.txt and then get unrecognized arguments: test.dat

usage: script.py [-h] [-c C] [-l] [-r] [-a]
addtofile.py: error: unrecognized arguments: test.dat